# java.io.IOException: Permission denied in Java

Tags: java, file, permissions, file-permissions, user-permissions

I am trying to create a file into the same folder in my project, but I am not able to create that file dynamically. I am trying this:

```
try {
            System.out.println("path"+System.getProperty("user.dir"));
            File file = new File("/textfile.txt");
            file.createNewFile();
            //file.createNewFile();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

What I am getting error is this:

```
java.io.IOException: Permission denied
```

Any suggestion will be welcomed.

Comment: /textfile.txt  should be changed to textfile.txt to place the file in the same project folder.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

To create a File into the same folder in your project, your path has to be relative.

The path that you are giving is absolute, because it is starting from `/`. For your path to be relative, remove `/` from the path and try this :

```
File file = new File("textfile.txt");
```

Comment: i tried its working . :D but why its giving that time exception?

Comment: you were trying to create a file in the root / directory of your linux computer and you may not be executing the java program as a root user, hence the exception.

Comment: but if i do like this '/' so that means i am trying to do in root directory is it?

Comment: Yes, refer this : http://www.linuxnix.com/2012/07/abslute-path-vs-relative-path-in-linuxunix.html

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is to create a variable string, store the file name, and pass that string into the `File file=new File(string);`

Comment: ya that is right too. i can do that but thing is that for the absolute path was saying :) it was onto the root directory prob.

Comment: This is fit to be a comment, than an answer.

Comment: @codeMan its fine i accept your ans okey now dont be more argumentative and ya he is also right about this.

Comment: @Krishna I have no intention of arguing or offending, It was just a comment. I completely agree that there is nothing wrong with Harsh Parikh's answer. but I dont see it solving the problem.

Comment: @codeMan Yes bro its just good that he tried :) and ya your ans was Solving problem that is true :)